# Windows 8 SDK renamed all headers and I don't know what to include now?

Tags: sdk, windows-8, winapi, directx-11

These are my headers from before I updated to the new SDK:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _EXTERNAL_DEPENDENCIES_H_
#define _EXTERNAL_DEPENDENCIES_H_

#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pdh.h>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
#include <xaudio2.h>
#include <x3daudio.h>
#include <xaudio2fx.h>
#include <ogg\ogg.h>
#include <ogg\os_types.h>
#include <vorbis\codec.h>
#include <vorbis\vorbisenc.h>
#include <vorbis\vorbisfile.h>

#include "d3dx11Effect.h"
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
#include <dxerr.h>
#include <dinput.h>
#include <d3dcommon.h>
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <d3dx10math.h>
#include <d3dx11async.h>
#include <D3DX11tex.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "gdiplus.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid.lib")  
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9d.lib")  
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10d.lib")  
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")  
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")        
#pragma comment (lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxerr.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "wsock32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dinput8.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "pdh.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "xaudio2.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "x3daudio.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libogg.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libogg_static.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libvorbis.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libvorbisfile.lib")

#pragma warning (disable : 4482)

#endif
```

Atleast half of them are missing in the new SDK...

Most of the core DirectX headers are renamed, I got around that, but half of them are just missing, like Dxerr.h and d3dx11async.h and even d3dx10math.h/xnamath.h (oh and when I include DirectXMath.h it still says that XMFLOAT3 is undefined). I don't know what to do now, does it say anywhere how to migrate from the June 2010 DirectX SDK to the Windows SDK 8.0?

Comment: (THE SITE BUGGED AND IT DOESNT SHOW THE FULL POST,SO HERE IT IS:)
Most of the core DirectX headers are renamed,I got around that,but half of them are just missing,like Dxerr.h and d3dx11async.h,and even <d3dx10math.h/xnamath.h(oh and when I include DirectXMath.h it still says that XMFLOAT3 is undefined.I don't know what to do now,does it say anywhere how to migrate from the June 2010 DirectX SDK to the Windows SDK 8.0?

Comment: Please remove this comment and please watch next time what you are putting in the text. You have used `<` mark and the browsers interpreted the following text as a HTML tag.

Answer (score 10):

XMFLOAT3 in DirectXMath.h is in namespace DirectX.

Try adding the following in the header file:

```
using namespace DirectX;
```

You can also include `<xnamath.h>` instead of directly including `<DirectXMath.h>` or `<D3DX10Math.h>`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the notes from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx#sdk_vs11 ? especially points 5 and 7,8,9,10 are important.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` through the new headers for functions you use from headers that are now missing. Or else MSDN documentation for the functions might tell you what header file you need.